# Delete using PHP and cURL

Tags: php, facebook, curl

Im still building the Facebook Build in like system to my site... and this is the cURL code to create the like action:

```
curl -F 'access_token=AAAAAKcSOZB8IBACXBZBQ1F5fUqqEeueY0bkj7eAZAeAWgjU5vU8c8ZC5X8L1ZAWGYVTlR0vySQQU0raZCuNCmPlcjxavrG6hsZD' \
     -F 'object=http://samples.ogp.me/226075010839791' \
        'https://graph.facebook.com/me/og.likes'
```

And it work on PHP by doing this code

```
$attachment =  array(
'access_token' => 'AAAAAKcSOZB8IBACXBZBQ1F5fUqqEeueY0bkj7eAZAeAWgjU5vU8c8ZC5X8L1ZAWGYVTlR0vySQQU0raZCuNCmPlcjxavrG6hsZD',
'object' => 'http://samples.ogp.me/226075010839791',
'actions' => json_encode(array('name' => $action_name,'link' => $action_link))
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'https://graph.facebook.com/me/og.likes');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $attachment);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  //to suppress the curl output 
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);

$obj = json_decode($result);
$idrespond =  $obj->{'id'};
```

Facebook sends back a 17 digit number (**$idrespond**) which I store in my SQL because is requiere to delete the like...

What I dont know how to do, is use the DELETE function in the cURL... facebook says this is the code to delete the like:

```
curl -X DELETE \
     -F 'access_token=AAAAAKcSOZB8IBACXBZBQ1F5fUqqEeueY0bkj7eAZAeAWgjU5vU8c8ZC5X8L1ZAWGYVTlR0vySQQU0raZCuNCmPlcjxavrG6hsZD' \
        'https://graph.facebook.com/{'{id_from_create_call}'}'
```

How can I apply this in php??

Comment: Why build and execute requests manually – when there’s the PHP SDK, that makes this all a lot easier …?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the option `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST` and set this to `DELETE`. The URL parameters will still be set with `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'DELETE');
```

From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php):

> A custom request method to use instead of "GET" or "HEAD" when doing a HTTP request. This is useful for doing "DELETE" or other, more obscure HTTP requests. Valid values are things like "GET", "POST", "CONNECT" and so on; i.e. Do not enter a whole HTTP request line here. For instance, entering "GET /index.html HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n" would be incorrect.